# How to send Outlook messages by javascript SDK?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I searched for a long time but I did not find a relevant solution.

When I send mail via Microsoft Graph API to get `403`, I do not know where the problem is

```json
{
    statusCode: 403, 
    code: "ErrorAccessDenied", 
    message: "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
}
```

Code:

makeSilentTokenRequest

```js
//The static key authentication request
function makeSilentTokenRequest(callback) {

    // Build up a hidden iframe
    var iframe = $('<iframe/>');
    iframe.attr('id', 'auth-iframe');
    iframe.attr('name', 'auth-iframe');
    iframe.appendTo('body');
    iframe.hide();

    iframe.load(function () {
        callback(localStorage.accessToken);
    });

    iframe.attr('src', buildAuthUrl() + '&prompt=none&domain_hint=' +
        localStorage.userDomainType + '&login_hint=' +
        localStorage.userSigninName);

}
```

getAccessToken

```js
//Verify refresh token function
function getAccessToken(callback) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var isExpired = now > parseInt(localStorage.tokenExpires);

    // Do we have a token already?
    if (localStorage.accessToken && !isExpired) {
        // Just return what we have
        if (callback) {
            callback(localStorage.accessToken);
        }
    } else {
        // Attempt to do a hidden iframe request
        makeSilentTokenRequest(callback);
    }
}
```

getUserEmailAddress

```js
function getUserEmailAddress(callback) {
    //I saved it in localStorage
    if (localStorage.userEmail) {
        return localStorage.userEmail;
    } else {
        //getAccessToken
        getAccessToken(function (accessToken) {
            if (accessToken) {
                // Create a Graph client
                var client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
                    authProvider: (done) => {
                        // Just return the token
                        done(null, accessToken);
                    }
                });
                // Get the Graph /Me endpoint to get user email address
                client
                    .api('/me')
                    .get((err, res) => {
                        if (err) {
                            callback(null, err);
                        } else {
                            callback(res.mail);
                        }
                    });
            } else {
                var error = {
                    responseText: 'Could not retrieve access token'
                };
                callback(null, error);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

sendMail

```js
//sendMail
function sendMail(message) {
    getUserEmailAddress(function (userEmail, error) {
        if (error) {
            renderError('getUserEmailAddress failed', error.responseText);
        } else {
            getAccessToken(function (accessToken) {
                if (accessToken) {
                    // Create a Graph client
                    var client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
                        authProvider: (done) => {
                            // Just return the token
                            done(null, accessToken);
                        }
                    });
                    client
                        .api('/me/sendMail')
                        .header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken)
                        .header('Content-Type', "application/json")
                        .post(message, (err, res) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                                //callback(null, err);
                            } else {
                                console.log(res);
                                //callback(res.value);
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    var error = {
                        responseText: 'Could not retrieve access token'
                    };
                    //callback(null, error);
                }
            });
        }
    })
}
```

createMail

```
function createMail(message,callback){
        getUserEmailAddress(function(userEmail, error) {
            if (error) {
                renderError('getUserEmailAddress failed', error.responseText);
            } else {
                getAccessToken(function(accessToken) {
                    if (accessToken) {
                        // Create a Graph client
                        var client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
                            authProvider: (done) => {
                                // Just return the token
                                done(null, accessToken);
                            }
                        });
                        client
                            .api('/me/messages')
                            .header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +accessToken)
                            .header('Content-Type', "application/json")
                            .post(message,(err, res) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    callback(res);
                                    console.log("创建失败！");
                                } else {
                                    callback(res);
                                    console.log("创建成功！");
                                }
                            });
                    } else {
                        var error = { responseText: 'Could not retrieve access token' };
                        //callback(null, error);
                    }
                });
            }
    })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough to go on here but the error message is telling you that your `accessToken` isn't valid.

I can't see which scopes are you requesting or which authorization workflow you executing so I can't pinpoint precisely why it is invalid.

Comment: Thanks in advance，I put the method of use into the problem.I'm using Microsoft's way to get to `accessToken`, and I can get the mailing list normally, but there's a problem when sending mail. What's the special point I need to pay attention to?

Comment: So we have quite a FEW "Microsoft Ways" of obtaining an `accessToken`. There are multiple endpoints (v1.0 vs v2.0) and multiple OAUTH flows (`authorization_code`, `implicit`, `client_credentials`), not to mention multiple APIs with their own scope set (Microsoft Graph API, Azure Graph API, Exchange Web Services, Yammer API, etc., etc.). Understanding exactly how you're obtaining the token will tell me why it is being rejected in this case.

Comment: Thanks,I don't think I made it clear, I am using the  [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_sendmail)

Comment: I made changes based on [javascript-tutorial](https://github.com/jasonjoh/javascript-tutorial)

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the problem because I didn't have the authority to send mail.I have questions about Outlook later. May I ask you?

Comment: I'm confused about the attachment.Microsoft offers a way, but I don't know how to use it.[fileAttachment](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/fileattachment)

Comment: Feel free to add another question. It also helps to reference any samples you're using in the question. In this case, the author of that sample is a regular on SO. :)

Comment: Thanks,I'll do that. You're earlier today than ever. :)